# Why does rebol return error with https

Tags: rebol

According to this page http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssl.html https is supported

but when trying with https://dzone.com I got this error

> ** Access Error: Invalid port spec: https://dzone.com
>
> ** Near: read https://dzone.com

Comment: On which platform are you trying it? Which Rebol product/version do you have?

Comment: I downloaded latest version of rebol (not rebolview) from the official website for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation page you linked especially mentions Rebol/View requirement for SSL support:

```
This feature is now available in REBOL/View as of 2.7.7.
```

Comment: OK thanks it works with rebolview (I didn't need view and I didn't expect rebol standalone would not integrate the same core functionality)

Comment: We have started to see site specific failures of Rebol 2's SSL support. I think it is due to websites upgrading from TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2. Rebol 2 doesn't support TLS 1.2.